# Hierarchical indexing in R dataframe

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a CSV file that I'm trying to read into a dataframe in R, and I was wondering how I might go about storing it with hierarchical indexing.  In other words, I want to make something with column names like this:

```
('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a1', 'b1', 'c2'), ('a1', 'b1', 'c3'), ('a1', 'b1', 'c4'),
('a1', 'b2', 'c1'), ('a1', 'b2', 'c2'), ('a1', 'b2', 'c3'), ('a1', 'b2', 'c4'),
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24
```

Turn out like this:

```
_________________________________________________
||                      a1                     ||
_________________________________________________
||          b1          ||          b2         ||
_________________________________________________
||  c1 | c2 | c3 | c4   ||   c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 ||
_________________________________________________
||  1  |  2 |  3 |  4   ||    5 |  6 |  7 |  8 ||
||  9  | 10 | 11 | 12   ||   13 | 14 | 15 | 16 ||
||  17 | 18 | 19 | 20   ||   21 | 22 | 23 | 24 ||
_________________________________________________
```

When converted into an R dataframe.  How exactly would I go about doing that?  I am new to R although I'm pretty familiar with Pandas dataframes in Python.  Thanks

Comment: What you show doesn't fit into a data.frame. It should be a nested list. Can't help you more because I don't understand how your input looks like.

Comment: ...or a melted "long" data frame.

Comment: That's not a thing. Data.frames are flat square boxes of data. You might consider using lists but it really depends on how you're going to process this data.

Comment: @MrFlick "Data.frames are flat square boxes of data".  So there's no option for something like this in R?  I wasn't sure if data.frames were flat or not.

Comment: @Roland I will edit my post to try and make it clearer.

Comment: Data frames are designed from a statistical perspective, where the row is the fundamental unit of data organization. We routinely deal with hierarchical data, but we organize it by putting each "level" in a column, which indicates groups.

Comment: @weskpga A data.frame is itself basically a list, but it has a few convenience functions that make your life easier if your data is a square table of atomic values in equal numbers of rows and columns. If that's not how your data is stored, you wont gain anything by shoving it into a data.frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hesitate to put this in an answer, but it's the only way to illustrate what I'm talking about. In R, we would take hierarchical data like what you provided and store it like this:

```
df <- data.frame(grp1 = 'a1',
                 grp2 = rep(c('b1','b2'),each = 4),
                 grp3 = rep(c('c1','c2','c3','c4'),times = 2))
> df
  grp1 grp2 grp3
1   a1   b1   c1
2   a1   b1   c2
3   a1   b1   c3
4   a1   b1   c4
5   a1   b2   c1
6   a1   b2   c2
7   a1   b2   c3
8   a1   b2   c4
```

If you have further groups, or levels, you'd add more columns and replicate the previous columns as needed.

Comment: This exactly answers my question, which was poorly worded.  Thank you.