# Combine Dataframe columns based on metadata information in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, hierarchical-data, data-manipulation

My dataset here is similar in concept to the one in this question: [Hierarchical indexing in R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334202/hierarchical-indexing-in-r-dataframe) but not this one: [R: Combine columns based on different information in another column of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224654/r-combine-columns-based-on-different-information-in-another-column-of-a-datafra)

I would like to combine (or regroup) columns in my table, by summing them,  based on metadata information on the columns in another dataframe.

Here is a an example of my datasets

```
  organisms x1 x2 x3 x4 y1 y2 y3 y4
       cat   1  1  5  0  1  0  1  3
       dog   2  2  4  0  2  3  0  1
     mouse   3  0  3  2  3  2  1  0
      bird   4  3  2  1  2  7  2  0
```

and this is how I one way I want to show it

```
organisms Extreme NotExtreme
cat       7 5
dog       8 6
mouse     8 6
bird      10 11
```

or as

```
organisms XLow XHigh YLow YHigh
cat         6    1     2     2    
dog         6    2     2     4
mouse       6    2     4     2
bird        6    4     4     7
```

Here is the code to load my datasets

```
metadata <- data.frame(sample = c("x1","x2","x3","x4","y1","y2","y3","y4"), treatment = c(rep("Xtreme",4),rep("NotExtreme",4)),dosage=c(rep(c("Xlow","Xhigh"),2),rep(c("Ylow","YHigh"),2)))
mydata <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,4), x2 = c(1,2,0,3), x3=c(5,4,3,2),x4=c(0,0,2,1),y1=c(1,2,3,2),y2=c(0,3,2,7),y3=c(1,0,1,2),y4=c(3,1,0,0))
rownames(mydata)<- c("cat","dog","mouse","bird")
```

Is there a straight-forward one or two liner solution or do I have to write a function for that? I looked into the melt function and the dplyr package, but this is not what I want here, since my data is already contained in two separate data.frames. This is a column dependent operation.

The [Hierarchical indexing in R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334202/hierarchical-indexing-in-r-dataframe) question is somehow similar to mine, but I do a re-presentation of the data, not keeping the hierarchy in the same dataframe. But the hierarchical relationship among the columns remains.

Any insights towards how to approach an elegant solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more elegant approach, but you can do this by subsetting based on a list of values from the metadata df and then summing those row values...

```
Exdf<-data.frame(Extreme=rowSums(mydata[,(colnames(mydata) %in% subset(metadata, treatment=="Xtreme")$sample==T)]),
             NotExtreme=rowSums(mydata[,(colnames(mydata) %in% subset(metadata, treatment=="NotExtreme")$sample==T)]))
LH<-data.frame(XLow=rowSums(mydata[,(colnames(mydata) %in% subset(metadata, dosage=="Xlow")$sample==T)]),
             XHigh=rowSums(mydata[,(colnames(mydata) %in% subset(metadata, dosage=="Xhigh")$sample==T)]),
           YLow=rowSums(mydata[,(colnames(mydata) %in% subset(metadata, dosage=="Ylow")$sample==T)]),
           YHigh=rowSums(mydata[,(colnames(mydata) %in% subset(metadata, dosage=="Yhigh")$sample==T)]))
```